# GRUB loads into CommandLine in Linux and Windows 10 dual boot (not rescue mode)

Tags: linux, boot, grub, uefi

First of all, I know this question has been asked on MANY forums many times over and over again. But for me, not one of the mentioned answers helped in any way.

My situation is a bit messy as I would say, so I will try to explain as good as possible.

I am dual booting Windows 10 and PopOS 20.10 on my Laptop. What was PopOS is now only LightDM with DWM and many changes were made to it. I used to choose the system I boot into with [rEFInd](https://rodsbooks.com/refind/), though I had some problems with that after a while.

I also distro-hopped quite a few times and I think that's where the multiple boot entries in my BIOS came from.

I am looking forward to:

1. Make GRUB not boot into command line ( not rescue mode ) anymore, so I don't have to do `set prefix` and `set root` at boot.
2. Clean up the boot entries. I hope this is the right information: [content of /boot/efi/EFI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIcbR.png)
3. ( Completely optional, only if someone has the time and wants to help me with it. )
   I would love to remove LightDM and start using a xinitrc to startx and launch default programs and scripts. I am not sure how to do this safely without screwing things up. ( I need my laptop for school. )

I am sorry for this total bloat of random information and problems, I know how it must come across, but I would really appreciate some help with this, I REALLY tried so much stuff already and I don't know any further.

Comment: If you select the correct entry in UEFI > Boot you shouldn't have to do #1. Then you can run `efibotmgr` to list and eventually delete the obsoleted entries.

Comment: Do you mean Select UEFI > Boot in my BIOS? I tried every single option and the ones that work, load the Command Line.

Comment: I actually meant UEFI, the firmware that replaced BIOS a decade ago :) Users (and sadly) manufacturers keep using the old acronym wrongly. First, after successfully booting Pop_OS (??) please run `sudo update-grub`. If it doesn't work then you may try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks for getting me up to date, although I should have given you more information. I already tried Boot Repair, both regular and custom mode, purged grub, reinstalled and I still get no result. I also ran ```sudo update-grub```.

Comment: If you are close to giving up, and you don't want to reformat and reinstall (give up), then I suggest you start dividing up this mountain of problems into smaller parts that you can understand, and then tackle one by one. Also, I advise you not to experiment with a computer that you need to be fully functional for school, unless you have a clear understanding of how to restore it in case of failure.

Comment: Thanks for the response, appreciate what you try to tell me. But I am and was able to restore my Laptop and PC before that. I had to, because that's part of, at least my, learning progress. I really just need a way of pointing grub permanently to what I manually do when in grub command line. That's it. My other problems aren't as important.